# insert into hbase table using hive (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I created this table in hbase using hive successfully :

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_trades(key string, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "trades");
```

now I want to insert values in this table! what is the HiveQl query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert to your hive table(hbase_trades) ,since you have integrated both, the data will be queriable from hbase (trades) table. Hope this helps.